C++ function dispatch based on user defined input type category (C++11/14 friendly)
I want to dispatch functions based on user defined "tag" of my input types. For example, I defined a tag called SomeSpecificObjectType and in class Object I mark this class as a SomeSpecificObjectType.
struct SomeSpecificObjectType{};

template<typename T>
class Object
{
    public:
    Object(T&&in): m_data(in){};
    typedef SomeSpecificObjectType ObjectTag;  
    T m_data;
};

Now I have another object, which doesnt share this tag. So I dont touch it.
template<typename T>
class OtherObject
{
    public:
    OtherObject(T&&in): m_data(in){};
    T m_data;
};

Now I define a struct to check for the tag I defined above.
template<typename T, typename Enable=void>
struct is_some_specific_object_type
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_some_specific_object_type<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename T::ObjectTag, SomeSpecificObjectType>::value>::type>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

My functions:
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<!is_some_specific_object_type<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void some_func(const T & data)
{
    std::cout <<"something" <<std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<is_some_specific_object_type<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void some_func(const T & data)
{
    std::cout <<"something else" << std::endl;
}

This seems work.
However, imagine I have class where its definition is hidden from me (HiddenObject) - this means I am unable to just add the "tag" SomeSpecificObjectType to this class. Essentially I want is_some_specific_object_type::value == true for this HiddenObject. Is there a way to do it without edditing the class HiddenObject
template<typename T>
class HiddenObject
{
    public:
    HiddenObject(T&&in): m_data(in){};
    T m_data;
};

Final desired result:
int main()
{
    Object obj(123);
    OtherObject o_obj(123);

    some_func(obj);
    some_func(o_obj);

    //HiddenObject h_obj(123);
    //some_func(h_obj); ---> print "something else"

    return 0;
}

Eddit:
Someone didnt like I used the word "trait", I will repalce this word with Tag, seems more fitting to avoid confusion.

That's not what traits mean in C++. See std::iterator_traits for example, and also the answer to your question.

Did you try putting that "trait" into a separate template class, so you can just specialize it for different classes? It's getting into black-belt template magic, but you could even try making the default implementation look up the "trait" in the class itself, so you can just put it there like in your first example for your own class, and only need to worry about specialization for classes outside your realm.

"Is there a way to do it without edditing the class HiddenObject": If you follow the tag approach instead of checking actual properties of the type that you need, as "traits" in C++ usually do, then you can of course simply specialize is_some_specific_object_type for that specific type. But this specialization needs to be put either in the header of HiddenObject or in the header defining is_some_specific_object_type before any first use of the trait on that specific type, possibly with forward-declaration to achieve this, otherwise you risk accidentally causing ODR violations.

@Passer By - I will have a look

@user17732522 Yes, this is exactly what I need, not sure why this went over my head. Thanks

Just add specialization of is_some_specific_object_type for HiddenObject:
template <typename T> struct is_HiddenObject : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_HiddenObject<HiddenObject<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_some_specific_object_type<T, std::enable_if_t<is_HiddenObject<T>::value>> : std::true_type{};

Demo
Notice that you might have to add/rearrange the specializations if your type (HiddenObject) matches several specializations.

For some reason, this solution went over my head. I could just had done this! Thanks for your help!
